# ffmpeg resize "could not find codec parameters"

Tags: installation, video, ffmpeg, resize

I'm a newbee to ubuntu and need your help: (32bit ubuntu 12.10) my command:

```
ffmpeg -i ../output_images/particles%04d.png -r 30 -b 30000k final_movie.avi
```

works for my 800x800 *.png pictures properly, but it doesn't with 512x512 *.png. There I get the following message:

```
[image2 @ 0x938a100] Could not find codec parameters (Video: png, 512x512)
```

On the campus-machines it works for both with the same code. I tried doing a resize-command:

```
for p in *.tga; do convert -resize 800x800 $p $p; done
```

With this added, it works, but I have and 800x800-movie in the end.

---

I've already installed the following packages:

Glut:

```
sudo apt-get install freeglut3-dev
```

ffmpeg:

```
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
```

There was a "curl command not found" error. I fixed it with:

```
sudo apt-get install curl
```

There was another "convert: command not found" and I fixed it with:

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```

Any idea what is missing?

Comment: Probably a bug in the buggy, bizarro, fake version of "ffmpeg" from libav. Try a [static build](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html#LinuxBuilds) of real ffmpeg from FFmpeg.

Comment: thx, can you tell me how I do that? (command?)

Comment: Yes, I should have included that. See [this example](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2121268&p=12536453&viewfull=1#post12536453).

Comment: @Lord I followed the instructions but still get the "Copyright (c) 2000-2012 the Libav developers" and not "Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers".

Comment: You need to make sure you're executing the `ffmpeg` binary properly. Either navigate to the directory containing `ffmpeg` and run `./ffmpeg -i input ... output` (notice the ./) or provide the full path to it as in `/home/andy/ffmpeg/ffmpeg -i input ... output`.

Comment: Changing the code to the path and it works now with the png's :D . Any way to make it the default operation when using ffmpeg? Would be good, otherwise I'd have to change all the files that I get to run. Any idea? (tyvm so far!!!)

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand the question. Can you clarify?

Comment: I'd like to know, if it is possible to set the "FFmpeg developers" version to standard instead of the "libav" one. So that when I run ffmpeg in any folder directly with ./ffmpeg that it will use the new one by default.

Comment: You have several options, but the "best" method is to place the `ffmpeg` binary in a directory and add the directory to your `$PATH` as shown in [How to add a directory to my path?](http://askubuntu.com/q/60218/59378).

Comment: perfect, that helped, error is fixed!!! Is it ok for you, if I'll make an answer to this thread containing all necessary commands? (ofc saying they're from you)

Comment: I'll just add an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### A misleading situation

First of all, the so-called "ffmpeg" from the Ubuntu repository is not really ffmpeg from the FFmpeg project, but a fake version from a fork. It's a confusing situation. See:

- [Who can tell me the difference and relation between ffmpeg, libav, and avconv?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9477756/1109017)
- [The FFmpeg/Libav situation](http://blog.pkh.me/p/13-the-ffmpeg-libav-situation.html)

Secondly, this fake "ffmpeg" (and avconv) are terribly buggy. FFmpeg development is very active, and using a recent version of real ffmpeg will most likely resolve this issue.

#### Getting the real `ffmpeg`

You have several options:

- [Compile ffmpeg on Ubuntu](https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/UbuntuCompilationGuide) - customizable, gives most recent code, but you must compile (not that hard and shouldn't take too long). Non-intrusive to the system.
- [Use a static build](http://ffmpeg.gusari.org/static/) - easiest to use but not customizable; also non-intrusive.
- [Use Jon Severinsson's FFmpeg PPA](https://launchpad.net/~jon-severinsson/+archive/ffmpeg) - easy to enable and install but old and not customizable

Each has their advantages and disadvantages as described above.

#### Using a static build

You just need to download the archive, extract it, and execute the binary. No compiling or installing is necessary:

```
wget http://ffmpeg.gusari.org/static/32bit/ffmpeg.static.32bit.2013-06-19.tar.gz
tar xzvf ffmpeg.static.32bit.2013-03-19.tar.gz
```

Now you can use it. You can either navigate to the directory containing `ffmpeg`, and run (notice the preceding `./`):

```
./ffmpeg -i input ... output
```

...or provide the full path to it as in:

```
/home/andy/ffmpeg/ffmpeg -i input ... output
```

#### Choose your `$PATH`

If you want the real ffmpeg whenever you use the `ffmpeg` command without having to use `./` or having to provide a full path to the binary, then place the ffmpeg binary in the `bin` directory in your home:

```
mkdir ~/bin
mv ffmpeg ~/bin
hash -r
```

Now you can just run `ffmpeg` and you'll be ready to encode stuff. If you want to use a different directory other than `~/bin`, then you will have to add the directory to your `$PATH` as shown in [How to add a directory to my path?](https://askubuntu.com/q/60218/59378)

#### Checking for spies

Now using the `ffmpeg` command should show something like (note the "FFmpeg developers" phrase):

```
$ ffmpeg 
ffmpeg version N-54152-g730e07f Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
```

If it shows the following then you'll know that you are cursed and the fake version is still being used (note the "Libav developers" phrase):

```
$ ffmpeg
ffmpeg version 0.8.5-6:0.8.5-0ubuntu0.12.10.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2012 the Libav developers
```

Answer (score 0):

What helped me is to change the image conversion format from png to jpeg. So the makemovie.sh has to look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd output_images
for F in $(ls *.tga); 
do 
    convert -quality 100 $F ${F%.tga}.jpg; 
    #convert -quality 100 $F ${F%.tga}.png;
    rm $F;
    echo done with converting $F; 
done
cd ..

THISPATH=$(pwd)
export PATH=$PATH:${THISPATH}/ffmpeg/ffmpeg-install/bin/

echo Making the movie now...

cd final_movie
rm final_movie.avi
ffmpeg -i ../output_images/particles%04d.jpg -r 30 -b 30000k final_movie.avi
cd ..
```

Comment: you mean  convert the *.tga to *.jpg. Guess that would work as well, but maybe at some point we need the transparency of a png-picture for multiple layers. Plus it seems to work on other machines, but thx for the tip ;)