# How to configure ffmpeg from some build?

Tags: 13.04, ppa, ffmpeg

I'd like to ask if there is a option for rebuilding or reconfiguring FFmpeg from any repository. 'Cause i need to add libass, but there's no build with this library and i used ffmpeg from Jon Severisson's ppa when i had 12.10 but now i've upgraded to 13.04 and it isn't supported. So, is there any other option to install ffmpeg without compiling from source?

Comment: You may refer to this http://askubuntu.com/a/291219/44518 for configuring the same.

Comment: Completely off-topic but that sounds like an awful library.

Comment: @karan: yeah, i read this thread and i know that i can compile the latest ffmpeg from sources but i want to know if is there any other option. Eg. if i can rebuilt ffmpeg from the main repository (or just add some configuration). But thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[Burek's FFmpeg builds](http://ffmpeg.gusari.org/static/) support libass. Simply download, extract, and run. Another Ask Ubuntu answer has [instructions](https://askubuntu.com/a/270107/59378).

libass is used by the [`subtitles`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#subtitles-1) video filter. Also see the FFmpeg Wiki article [How to burn subtitles into the video](https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/How%20to%20burn%20subtitles%20into%20the%20video) if this is why you need support for this library.