# Every video editor crashing! [11GB AVI File vs Openshot & KDen Live]

Tags: crash, blender, kdenlive, openshot

After about 5-6 hours of waiting in Blender, I finally get an 11GB avi video file that is a audio visualisation of the song Stay With Me by Mendum generated by a script I made.

The file is rather massive if you ask me, and I kind of hate the thought that there is an 11gb file on my system that I am not using that is just eating up space.

My focus right now, is to get this video file edited and compressed to a reasonable size to upload to YouTube. (The song is copyright-free, that's not a problem)

I've tried importing the clip as well as the song and syncing it on both Kden Live and Openshot and both of them are constantly crashing.

If there's any free video editing software out that is reasonably stable and can be supported on a slow computer? Please let me know, it would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you have a video file that you want to make smaller I would use ffmpeg to recode it. It streams the video so doesn't need to load the entire thing into ram.

ffmpeg has a lot of options that you can find in the man page and you could find many examples online.

If you have a video only file then

```
ffmpeg -i movie.avi -vcodec mp4 -b 2M movie.conv.mp4
```

should give you a smaller mp4 video file you can load into kdenlive with the audio to sync up.

You can also use ffmpeg to mix the video and audio into one file. As you may only want to offset the audio start time this wouldn't be hard.

Comment: Thanks! But there's one problem. How do I obtain ffmpeg? As the Terminal only returns 'ffmpeg: command not found'.

Comment: if `sudo apt-get install ffmpeg` doesn't help read [through this](http://askubuntu.com/q/313217/183698)

Answer (score 0):

Add handbrake PPA from https://launchpad.net/~stebbins/+archive/ubuntu/handbrake-releases and install handbrake and compress your video. There is no FFMPEG in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS but later versions have it.